# SQL query doesn't finish

Tags: sql, performance

I run script, that select from table:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Portfolios]
where Delisted = 0 
  and BrokerAccountId is not null 
  and ImportType = 2
GO
```

Script of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Portfolios](
    [PortfolioId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsDefault] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Cash] [money] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentCash] [money] NULL,
    [Type] [int] NULL,
    [Delisted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CurrencyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TrackCashBalanceType] [int] NULL,
    [IsDividendReinvestment] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NULL,
    [FinancialInstitutionId] [int] NULL,
    [Configured] [bit] NULL,
    [BrokerAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [ImportType] [int] NULL,
    [PortfolioTotalValue] [money] NULL,
    [IsRequireNewCredentials] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Portfolios_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PortfolioId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [Portfolios_uq] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Guid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Usually, this script execute about 10 seconds. But now it doesn't finish, but when I cancel executing query in SQL Server all needed data read.

Any ideas why query doesn't finished?

Comment: If it runs when you append `(nolock)` to `[TradeStops3].[dbo].[Portfolios]` then some records are locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for locks on the table,

try below query

SELECT *
FROM [TradeStops3].[dbo].[Portfolios]/*(NOLOCK) use this */
where Delisted = 0 
  and BrokerAccountId is not null 
  and ImportType = 2
GO

Please update if it doesn't help.

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: With this option work. I think, that one row in table was blocked. Do you know how unlock this row?

Comment: Actually most of the time a when a table is lock this thing happens, you can see this link, http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic933313-391-1.aspx